# Python3 package distribution as .deb using PyPi dependencies?

Tags: python, debian, pypi, debhelper

When I build Python package into `.deb` to distribute, I have always been using `setuptools` and in my `debian/control` file I had following:

```
Package: myproject
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python3:Depends}, cron, ...
```

And I build the Python3 package as follows:

```bash
dh build --with python3 --buildsystem pybuild
```

[Documentation for pybuild says that you should never download python3 package dependencies from pypi and fully rely on debian package manager, aka `apt-get install python3-*`](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Pybuild) and actually adding `${python3:Depends}` in combination with disabled `debhelper's http_proxy` will do that trick, which basically forces to download all python3 dependencies from `apt repo`.

But the thing is that `python3-*` dependencies are not the latest in the `apt repo`, some of them are very outdated, like `sqlalchemy`, however my Python3 project, that I wish to distribute is using **the latest** dependencies.

How can I build my python3 project and then successfully install it on a computer using `dpkg buildpackage`, but being able to use `PyPi` dependencies, since they are latest and the ones my project uses?